# Delete the row if the cell value on sheet is the same then the cell value on another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I need to delete the row if the value of column G on a sheet named OV  is = the value on column G  on a sheet named all_teams. I am trying different approach, however when it works only deletes 1 row.

```
Sub test_delete()

    Dim j As Variant
    Dim ltrow As Long

    ltrow = OV.Range("C" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                    
    For j = 2 To ltrow
    
        If all_teams.Range("G" & j).Value = OV.Range("G" & ltrow).Value Then
                    OV.Rows(j).Delete
        End If
                
    Next j
        
End Sub
```

What would be the best approach for it?

Comment: Anyhow, the deletion should be done in reverse order, or even better loading the rows to be deleted in a range (using `Union`) and delete all of them at once... Your code **checks if the last value of "OV" worksheet is equal with all values in "G" of the worksheet  "all_teams"**. This is what you want? If you want checking each value of one sheet with each value of the second one, you must proceed in a different way.

Comment: Still alive? Can you clarify what from the two worksheets you want comparing? **Each values** or all the values of first sheet with **the last value** of the second one?

Comment: @FaneDuru yes, I need to delete the row on sheet **OV **when the value on **column G on sheet OV** is  the same the value on **Column G on sheet all_teams**.  
Normally sheet OV will have around 20 or more lines, however sheet all_teams will have more than 1000 lines

Comment: Then, try my answer code. It is untested. I must leave now. If something not working as you need, please explain what and I will solve it when I will be at home.

Comment: @FaneDuru I will try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next code, please. Please, properly set the used worksheets:

```
Sub test_delete()
    Dim OV As Worksheet, all_teams As Worksheet, lastROV As Long, lastRAllT As Long
    Dim i As Variant, j As Variant, rngDel As Range
    'you have to set here the sheets...

    lastROV = OV.Range("G" & cells.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    lastRAllT = all_teams.Range("G" & cells.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
                    
    For j = 2 To lastROV
        For i = 2 To lastRAllT
            If all_teams.Range("G" & i).Value = OV.Range("G" & j).Value Then
                If rngDel Is Nothing Then
                   Set rngDel = OV.Rows(j)
                Else
                    Set rngDel = Union(rngDel, OV.Rows(j))
                End If
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    Next j
    If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then rngDel.EntireRow.Delete xlUp
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you set the worksheet as I recommended? I am driving now...

Comment: @Fah: I am at home, now. I can see you marked the code as accepted answer. Did you make it working? Was the sheet setting problem? If not working, what error does it show? Or, does it something you do not need?

Answer (score 1):

Learnt this from one of my previous questions.

When deleting rows in a for loop, its best to do it backwards, so the following

`For j = ltRow To 2 Step -1`

I believe this could help you out!

```
sub test_delete()

dim j as variant
dim ltrow as long

ltrow = worksheets("OV").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

for j = ltRow to 2 Step -1
   if sheets("all_teams").Range("G" & J).Value = Sheets("OV").Range("G" & ltrow).value then
         Sheets("OV").Rows(J).entirerow.delete
    end if
next
end sub
```

untested, but I think it may work!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test_delete()

    Dim j As Variant
    Dim ltrow As Long
    Dim wsOV As Worksheet, wsAll As Worksheet

    With ThisWorkbook
        Set wsOV = .Worksheets("OV")
        Set wsAll = .Worksheets("all_teams")
    End With
    
    ltrow = wsOV.Range("C" & wsOV.Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                    
    For j = ltrow To 2 Step -1
    
        If wsAll.Range("G" & j).Value = wsOV.Range("G" & ltrow).Value Then
            wsOV.Rows(j).EntireColumn.Delete
        End If
                
    Next j
        
End Sub
```

Comment: I will try and let you know. Thank you